# tensorflow-gpu on Ubuntu. Problem with installation

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I'm trying to install **tensorflow** with **GPU** and I'm following the insructions from this  page: [tensorflow.org/install/pip#linux](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#linux) . When I try to verify the installation with the command **import tensorflow as tf** I get the following message:

[image]

Also,when I try

> print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))

to see if it has access to GPU, I get :

> [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

Does this mean that I did it correctly or not? I also browsed the "Build and install errors" thread on the mentioned page but didn't find a similar error or problem such the one showing  in th picture.

Comment: There has been compatibility issue of TensorRT with 2.10. Please check with TF-nightly and TensorRT 7.2.3.4 if you are trying to install TensorRT too. [Ref](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/57679#issuecomment-1255404860)